# How to update meta_value to wp_postmeta

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I'm make a my plugin. I want update this value

```
a:1:{i:0;s:22:{"include/archive/author";}
```

up to `wp_postmeta` tables with `update_post_meta()` method.

But İt is adding value while added addional value my meta value

`s:41:"a:1:{i:0;s:22:{"include/archive/author";}";`

How to adding only my value

```
a:1:{i:0;s:22:{"include/archive/author";}
```

Thanks.

Comment: please help me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are serializing a serialized string.

Your original array looks like this :

```
array(0=>'include/archive/author');
```

You're probably doing something like this:

```
update_post_meta($post_id,$meta_key,$author);
```

where you meant to do this:

```
update_post_meta($post_id,$meta_key,$author[0]);
```

Comment: `$yazar_post_id = $_POST['author_type'];`
   `$value = 'a:1:{i:0;s:22:{"include/archive/author";}';`
   `$a =update_post_meta( $post_id, '_elementor_conditions', $value );` @andrew

Comment: Just do `$value = 'include/archive/author'; $a =update_post_meta( $post_id_elementor_conditions', $value );` no need to serialize it

Comment: I dont know why you feel the need to serialize it. But if you want to do that you need  `$yazar_post_id = $_POST['author_type']; $value = array(0=>'include/update/author/'); $a =update_post_meta( $post_id, '_elementor_conditions', $value );`

Comment: Please help me please :(

Comment: Check my last comment

Comment: Thank you @andrew issue is fixed. No problem.